# how to make profiles for undetected chrome driver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i can not make profiles with undetectedchromedriver

```
using Selenium.WebDriver.UndetectedChromeDriver;
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
 var webBrowser=Selenium.WebDriver.UndetectedChromeDriver.UndetectedChromeDriver.Instance("profile"+i,options);
 webBrowser.GoTo("https://google.com");
webBrowser.Quit();
}
```

how to fix it ? thanks

i want to make it to become multiples threading with diffirent profiles